# Convert a AngularJS service to a typescript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, single-page-application

It's an AngularJS 1.7v codebase. I need to configure Typescript support and convert one existing .js file to a .ts file. I managed to configure typescript with `ts-loader`. But when I run the app, I get `core.js?a712:1752 ERROR Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: TestTSProvider <- TestTS` error with the Typescript service. What am I doing wrong?

This is the TS Service:

```
module something {
    export class TestTS {
        something() {
            return 'Hi';
        }

        static Factory() {
            return new TestTS();
        }
     }
}


 angular.module('app').factory('TestTS', something.TestTS.Factory);
```

and the Webpack configuration is:

```
          {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: [
                    /node_modules/,
                ],
            }
```

Comment: It's a common error of Angularjs results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined, imported and spelled correctly. Did you include your TS file correctly (I mean file name and the order of file)

Comment: Yes, the order and name is fine